# How to add "Share on whatsapp" button on mobile website for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, mobile-website, whatsapp

Adding whatsapp share button on website, for iOS8.
I am using the following:

```
<spanid="whatsapp_share_android">
    <a href="whatsapp://send?text={{my_meta.og_title.value}} - http://{{ request.get_host }}{{entity.url}}%3Futm_source=whatsapp%26utm_medium=referral" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" onmousedown="_paq.push(['trackEvent','Share on Whatsapp','Mobile','{{request.get_full_path}}']); ga('send', 'event','Share on Whatsapp','Mobile','{{request.get_full_path}}');ga('mobileTracker.send', 'event','Share on Whatsapp','Mobile','{{request.get_full_path}}');"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/whatsapp_icon.png" /></a>
</span>
```

It works on android but not on iOS

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the WhatsApp FAQ for app integration, your URL scheme should work:

- [I'm an iPhone developer, how can I integrate WhatsApp into my app?](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)
- [I'm an Android developer, how can I integrate WhatsApp with my app?](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

I assume that everything within brackets in your sample code will be replaced by your app? Also there needs to be a space between the `span` tag and its `id` attribute.

How about if you try it with this simple example on both platforms:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

Comment: how can we add description?

Answer (score 7):

As of 2021/03/01, [WhatsApp documentation](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app) states: *"Universal links are the preferred method of linking to a WhatsApp account. Use https://wa.me [...]"*

Example:

```
const whatsAppURL = `https://wa.me?text=${encodeURIComponent('The message to send')}`;
```

What's the difference with `whatsapp://`? `wa.me` works on desktop and mobile (hence the term "Universal links") while `whatsapp://` only works on mobile with the WhatsApp application installed.

`wa.me` even works with the web version of WhatsApp: https://web.whatsapp.com/

Comment: https://wa.me works for me, both for mobile and desktop.